# Getting values from all the indices of a list (Determining Prime Numbers)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

First and foremost I'm new to Python. I am trying to determine if a number, let's say 167 is a prime number by using the modulo operation, `%`.

E.g., 
Let `167 % n = some value i`

When `167 % 1` and `167 % 167`, it should return 0 and for n in `range(2,166)`, it should be giving the remainder of `167 % n`. The problem I have is that I am trying to print the remainder when `167 % n` for `n = 1 ~ 167` but don't know how to get the values (which should be the remainder) of the indices of a list.

So, here's what I have:

```
L  = [] #creates empty list
i=0     #initialize i? 
for i in range(1, 168) :
if 167 % i == 0  :
    print ("There is no remainder")
else :
    167 % i == x   # x should be the value of the remainder 
    L[i].append(x) #attempting to add x ... to the indices of a list. 
    print(L[x])    #print values of x.
```

It's even better if I can use the while loop, that should be much clearer. So, while `i` iterates from 1-167, it should be adding the results `x` into the indices of the list and I want to print those results.

Any recommendation guys? Any help appreciated!! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a list of all remainders that are not equal to zero:

```
L  = []
for i in range(1, 168) :
    remainder = 167 % i
    if remainder == 0  :
        print("There is no remainder")
    else:
        L.append(remainder)
        print(remainder)

>>> len(L)
165
```

There are a number of problems in your code:

- Your indentation is wrong.
- Setting `i = 0` before the loop does not make sense because it is not used before the loop and overridden in the loop.
- This: `167 % i == x` compares the remainder with a non-existing `x`. You want to assign the result to `x` with `x = 167 % i`.
- You try to append to an element of `L` at index `i` using `L[i].append(x)` but you want to append `x` to `L` with `L.append(x)`.
- Finally, you try to get the value you just added using `print(L[x])` but you need to use `print(L[i])`, simpler, just print `remainder` with `print(remainder)`.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that the list is redundant!